# Using Jquery .ajax method how can i read the query parameter and hit the web method and get the result in json on page load + asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using Asp.net with jquery I wanted to display information for a specific product that is getting from the query string so my question is

**How can i get the query string through jquery and hit the Web method and get the result in json and display that result on my page on page load.**

Thanks waiting for your replay..

Comment: Did you check the manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the window.location.href in order to get the query parameter. See [here](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) for example. You then need to make an Ajax call in the document ready function:

```
$(function() {
  // get query
  // make ajax call
  // get the results in json, display them
});
```

Because the results will load from the Ajax's method callback, they will appear slightly after the page has been loaded.